# SQL Statement - Based on Total Sum of a Column Type

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have an table of orders with the following columns:

`Model`
`Quantity`
`Price`
`ScheduleB`
`OrderID`

There can be multiple `Model` with the same `ScheduleB` classification.  I need a SQL statement that will only return a record where the total price (`Quantity` * `Price`) of all `Model` of similarly grouped `ScheduleB` classifications are greater than $2500 for an `OrderID`.  There are hundreds of different `ScheduleB` classifications possible.  So an example of what you might see in the table for `OrderID` = 10054 would be:

`+-------------------------------------------+`
`| Model | Qty | Price | ScheduleB | OrderID |`
`+-------------------------------------------+`
`Dr1625, 2, $1298.87, 1029202938, 10054`
`Dr1624, 1, $123.87,  1029202930, 10054`
`Dr1623, 5, $2499.87, 1029202931, 10054`
`Dr1622, 3, $600.87, 1029202938, 10054`
`Dr1621, 1, $3298.87, 1029202938, 10054`

The records with `ScheduleB` equal to 1029202938 have a combined total of greater than $2500, I would want the following returned:

`+-------------------------------------------+`
`| Model | Qty | Price | ScheduleB | OrderID |`
`+-------------------------------------------+`
`Dr1625, 2, $1298.87, 1029202938, 10054`
`Dr1622, 3, $600.87, 1029202938, 10054`
`Dr1621, 1, $3298.87, 1029202938, 10054`

Basically, I only want to show records from a table where the same `ScheduleB` classifications have a total price greater than $2500 for a specific `OrderID`.  Can this be done with a SQL statement in MYSQL?

EDIT:
Here is the SQL statement that I am using to get the above mentioned columns (plus a few others):
`select brands.Brand, products.Model_PartNumber, categories.CategoryDescription, (Select Sum(Quantity) From orderitems where OrderID = 10054 AND ProductID = products.ProductID Group BY ProductID) as Quantity, orderitems.ItemPrice, brands.CountryOrigin, categories.ScheduleB, products.Weight, products.WeightIn from orderitems INNER JOIN products ON products.ProductID = orderitems.ProductID INNER JOIN brands ON products.BrandID = brands.BrandID LEFT JOIN productcategories ON productcategories.ProductID = products.ProductID INNER Join categories ON productcategories.CategoryID = categories.CategoryID WHERE orderitems.OrderID = 10054 Group By products.Model_partNumber`

Comment: Have you tried anything ??

Comment: No, I have no idea.  It looks simple, but I just can't think of anything.

Comment: Try something first then post your query here... Else no ones gonna help you for your query...

Comment: If you do like this.. You will not learn things... So better next time do homework and if you dont get anything then try to post it here..

Comment: Well I have tried PHP with no luck.  I posted an edit above with my current SQL statement that works, but only gets the records and orders by Model_PartNumber

Comment: Er, if a model can only have one `ScheduleB` classification (whatever that is), it's in the wrong table - it belongs in table `Model`.  If there are different ones possible than it probably belongs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done:

```
Select 
Model
,Quantity
,Price
,ScheduleB
,OrderID
From Table1
WHERE ScheduleB IN 
  (SELECT ScheduleB FROM Table1 GROUP BY ScheduleB HAVING SUM(Quantity * Price) > 2500)
```

Comment: Can you look at my edit above?  How would I implement your SQL statement using the one from my edit?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach.  Use aggregation to calculate the total price for each `ScheduleB` and `OrderId` combination.  Then just keep the combos where the total exceeds $2,500.  Use this for filtering the original records:

```
select o.*
from orders o join
     (select OrderId, ScheduleB, sum(qty * price) as total
      from orders
      group by OrderId, ScheduleB
     ) os
     on o.orderId = os.orderId and
        o.ScheduleB = os.ScheduleB and
        total >= 2500;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL statement did the trick:

`Select ScheduleB from (select (Select Sum(Quantity) From orderitems where OrderID = ? AND ProductID = products.ProductID Group BY ProductID) as Quantity, orderitems.ItemPrice, categories.ScheduleB from orderitems INNER JOIN products ON products.ProductID = orderitems.ProductID  LEFT JOIN productcategories ON productcategories.ProductID = products.ProductID INNER Join categories ON productcategories.CategoryID = categories.CategoryID WHERE orderitems.OrderID = ? Group By products.ProductID) as table1 Group by ScheduleB Having SUM(Quantity * ItemPrice) > 2500;`

Thanks to both `Cha` and `Gordon` for pointing me in the right direction.